# combining these two methods into single one

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

Hi all i have two classes and i have two methods where i am passing these two classes into methods individually and checking `name` and `NarrativeHTML` and rendering bulleted list.

```
public class LibraryHydronicEquipment : AEIMasterBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HydronicEquipmentType? Type { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public List<HydronicSystemType> Systems { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public List<EquipmentProperty> Properties { get; set; }
    public string NarrativeHTML { get; set; }
}

public class LibrarySteamEquipment : AEIMasterBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SteamEquipmentType? Type { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public List<SteamSystemType> Systems { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public List<EquipmentProperty> Properties { get; set; }
    public string NarrativeHTML { get; set; }
  }
```

**Method 1:**

```
  private void BuildBulletedList(List<LibraryHydronicEquipment> libraryHydronicEquipments)
  {
        List<Run> labels = new List<Run>();
        foreach (var equipmentItem in libraryHydronicEquipments)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(equipmentItem.NarrativeHTML))
            {
                var htmlRuns = this.DocumentHtmlConverter.Parse(equipmentItem.NarrativeHTML)
                                                         .First()
                                                         .ChildElements
                                                         .Where(c => c is Run)
                                                         .Cast<Run>()
                                                         .Select(n => n.CloneNode(true));
                labels.Add(new Run(htmlRuns));
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(equipmentItem.Name))
            {
                labels.Add(new Run(new Text(equipmentItem.Name)));
            }
        }
        BuildList(labels);
  }
```

**Method 2**

```
  private void BuildBulletedList(List<LibrarySteamEquipment> librarySteamEquipments)
  {
        List<Run> labels = new List<Run>();
        foreach (var equipmentItem in librarySteamEquipments)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(equipmentItem.NarrativeHTML))
            {
                var htmlRuns = this.DocumentHtmlConverter.Parse(equipmentItem.NarrativeHTML)
                                                         .First()
                                                         .ChildElements
                                                         .Where(c => c is Run)
                                                         .Cast<Run>()
                                                         .Select(n => n.CloneNode(true));
                labels.Add(new Run(htmlRuns));
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(equipmentItem.Name))
            {
                labels.Add(new Run(new Text(equipmentItem.Name)));
            }
        }
        BuildList(labels);
  }
```

and i am calling these methods like as below

```
if (hydronicSystem.Equipment.Source.Count != 0)
{                       
      BuildBulletedList(hydronicSystem.Equipment.Source);
}
   
if (steamSystem.Equipment.Source.Count != 0)
{
     BuildBulletedList(steamSystem.Equipment.Source);
}
```

**update :**

```
 if (hydronicSystem.Equipment.Source.Count != 0)
 {
      BuildBulletedList(hydronicSystem.Equipment.Source);
 }
 if (hydronicSystem.Equipment.Distribution.Count != 0)
 {
      BuildBulletedList(hydronicSystem.Equipment.Distribution);
 }
 if (hydronicSystem.Equipment.Terminals.Count != 0)
 {
      BuildBulletedList(hydronicSystem.Equipment.Terminals);
 }
```

Is there any way we can combine these two methods into single generic method?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Change the signature to `private void BuildBulletedList(List<AEIMasterBase> equipments)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the shared members into a base type

```
public interface IRender {
    string Name { get; set; }
    string NarrativeHTML { get; set; }
}
```

and have the classes derive from that type

```
public class LibraryHydronicEquipment : AEIMasterBase, IRender {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HydronicEquipmentType? Type { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public List<HydronicSystemType> Systems { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public List<EquipmentProperty> Properties { get; set; }
    public string NarrativeHTML { get; set; }
}

public class LibrarySteamEquipment : AEIMasterBase, IRender {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SteamEquipmentType? Type { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public List<SteamSystemType> Systems { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public List<EquipmentProperty> Properties { get; set; }
    public string NarrativeHTML { get; set; }
}
```

then refactor the method to depend on that type via generics

```
private void BuildBulletedList<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : IRender {
    List<Run> labels = new List<Run>();
    foreach (T item in items) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.NarrativeHTML)) {
            var htmlRuns = DocumentHtmlConverter
                .Parse(item.NarrativeHTML)
                .First()
                .ChildElements
                .Where(c => c is Run)
                .Cast<Run>()
                .Select(n => n.CloneNode(true));
            labels.Add(new Run(htmlRuns));
        } else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name)) {
            labels.Add(new Run(new Text(item.Name)));
        }
    }
    BuildList(labels);
}
```

Now to make a single call, concatenate the lists and then check to see if a bullet list can be built.

```
var source = hydronicSystem.Equipment.Source.Cast<IRender>();
var distribution = hydronicSystem.Equipment.Distribution.Cast<IRender>();
var terminals = hydronicSystem.Equipment.Terminals.Cast<IRender>();

var bullets = source.Concat(distribution).Concat(terminals);
if (bullets.Any()) {
    BuildBulletedList(bullets);
}
```